# Call back notification in FASTAPI(how to use it in other endpoint)

Tags: push-notification, callback, fastapi

I am calling an API in my FASTAPI microservice, They made a notification system, Like whenever i hit their API I will be getting a completed or failed notification through post request which i have created in my FASTAPI microservice(Different End Point). So whenever I am hitting their API i will get the notification in my post request endpoint, That completed or failed response I need to use in my actual endpoint, How can i use it.

I have just update that call back status in my DB, But there are two different sessions, so i am not getting the updated values in my actual endpoint.

Comment: I think it's impossible to help you until you show us some code. Try to create minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @requests_router.post(
    '/data/integration', response_model = MetaDataSchema,
    status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, 
)
def integration(
    request_data: RequestSchema,
    db: Session = Depends(get_session)
):
    
    try: 
        classification_request = uuid_request(request_data.doc_id)

This is the code for first endpoint where we are calling the other API

Comment: @requests_router.post(
    '/classification',
    status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, 
)
def call_back_request(
    request_call_back: RequestCallBack,
    db: Session = Depends(get_session)
):
    try: 
        logger.info("call back request triggered")
        res = validate_uuid(db, request_call_back.request_uuid)
        if res:
            doc_type = ""
            if request_call_back.status == "COMPLETED":
                doc_type = classification_data(request_call_back.request_uuid)
            logger.info("doc_type fetched {doc_type}")

Notification endpoint

Comment: Please, include code in your question (you can edit it) and use `code` block to make it readable